# Window and Page overlap

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to build a WPF app and I should display the collection in MyPage. I have created a button in MainWindow which triggers the LoadCollection() and displays it in MyPage but it does so overlapping the objects I have in MainWindow.

Can anyone point me into the right direction ? What am I missing ? 
Shouldn't the page be like a "clean sheet" ?

This is my MainWindow.xaml code:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Welcome to Stefan's Test</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="114,54,93,0" Width="310">Start your test by choosing the difficulty</TextBlock>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Beginner" MinWidth ="100" Click="BtnClickP1"/>
        <Button Content="Intermediate" MinWidth="100" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" Click="BtnClickP2"/>
        <Button Content="Expert" MinWidth="100" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" Click="BtnClickP3"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame x:Name="Main" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"></Frame>
```

Comment: Please paste your MainWindow.xaml code here.

Comment: I have pasted the code, Raviraj Palvankar. Is it helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a paren container panel like a Grid, Dock etc.

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Welcome to Stefan's Test</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="114,54,93,0" Width="310">Start your test by choosing the difficulty</TextBlock>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Beginner" MinWidth ="100"/>
        <Button Content="Intermediate" MinWidth="100" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>
        <Button Content="Expert" MinWidth="100" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame Grid.Row="3" x:Name="Main" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"></Frame>
</Grid>
```